# How to increase reputation from one

Tags: discussion

I am struggling with increasing my stackoverflow reputation from one.

I coming at this with the assumption that the reputation system has been designed with the intention of making it possible to measure individuals' contributions to the community. I am completely in favour of such a mechanism.

As far as I can tell, at a reputation of one, the only options for my raising reputation is to either ask or answer a question.

Surely, it's not that hard to ask or answer a question? Actually I think it is because, unless I want to duplicate an existing question or answer, or to provide a rushed or incomplete answer, searching stackoverflow for existing content is usually sufficient.

I do want to contribute as I feel the urge to pay back to the community; however I am finding that my low reputation is preventing me from doing this. For instance, whenever I try to vote up an answer, I am told my reputation is too low.

So far I have been resisting asking bogus questions and getting friends to answer them; however, unless I find a legitimate way of increasing my reputation, I suspect that I will eventually fold.

So my question is, how do I raise my reputation in a way that does not abuse the intention behind reputations!

Thanks.

P.S. Ironically, moments after asking this question, a previous answer I had posted was accepted and I was launched to 11 rep. It looks like I am out of the bootstrapping zone and I can start to contribute to the community. Thanks for the answers and comments folks.

Comment: Suggesting edits will also increase your reputation, but not by much. If you want more rep you need to ask and answer questions - if you don't really want to do that then that begs the question 'why have you signed up for the site in the first place'?

Comment: You can start by ensuring that you're doing proper research before submitting posts.  When you ask questions without doing your research first, [example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196462/186381), then your questions are likely to attract downvotes instead of upvotes.  We're looking for quality content and it *should* take you time an effort to generate it.  If it's not, there's likely something wrong.

Comment: Pick a topic of your interest and do this search: `[INTERESTING-TAG] answers:0 closed:no`. Much probably, you'll find a bunch of stuff worth answering (researching/learning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Surely, it's not that hard to ask or answer a question?

It isn't difficult to ask bad questions and give bad answers. It **is** difficult to post *good* content.

---

Another way to contribute and gain reputation is to make edits to posts - there are many posts that are unclear and suffer from bad grammar, have typos and terrible formatting. All these are things to fix in posts - if you do that, the edit becomes a suggested edit and if approved you gain 2 reputation for it, up to a limit of 1000 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has the same frustration.  Gaming the system with your friends invites detection by the SO discretizer and thus should be avoided.

If you want to gain rep through asking questions, the best way is to write lots of really hard and challenging code and you will have some good questions as a result.

If you want to gain rep through answering questions, the best way is to write lots of really hard and  challenging code and you will have some good answers as a result.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [suggested edits system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) which will allow you to contribute to the community by improving questions and answers. You should generally only make grammatical improvements and increase the readability of the posts. If your suggested edit is approved, you will receive 2 points. (The maximum that can be received in this system is 1k)